Custom picker, renderer migration to Handler issue
I'm currently working to refacto a custom renderer i did in the past into a MAUI Handler for a custom icon picker.
Currently i'm not able to make it work at all, the picker rendered on emulator is strictly the same as the default one.
My Custom control is as follow:
    public partial class IconPicker : Picker
    {
        [AutoBindable]
        private readonly ImageSource _source = null!;

        [AutoBindable(DefaultValue = "1.0")]
        private readonly double _strokeThickness;

        [AutoBindable]
        private readonly Color? _stroke;

        [AutoBindable]
        private readonly float _cornerRadius;
    }

The renderer i developed basically add a border (rounded or not) and an icon to the basic picker removing for android the underline:
[Obsolete("This renderer is obsolete, it will be replaced in future release by corresponding handler/mapper")]
public class IconPickerRenderer(Context context) : PickerRenderer(context)
{
    IconPicker? element;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        element = (IconPicker)this.Element;

        if (Control != null && this.Element != null && element.Source != null)
            Control.Background = SetPickerUi(element);
    }

    private LayerDrawable SetPickerUi(IconPicker element)
    {
        GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
        border.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        border.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        border.SetCornerRadius(element.CornerRadius);
        border.SetColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(element.BackgroundColor?.ToAndroid() ?? Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
        border.SetStroke(Convert.ToInt32(element.StrokeThickness), element.Stroke?.ToAndroid() ?? Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new([border, GetDrawable(element.Source).Result]);
        layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 20, 0, 0, 0);
        return layerDrawable;
    }

    private async Task<Drawable> GetDrawable(ImageSource source)
    {
        Drawable drawable;
        if (source is FontImageSource font)
            drawable = new FontDrawable(Context!, font.Glyph, font.Color.ToAndroid(), Convert.ToInt32(font.Size), "MaterialIconsRound-Regular.otf"); // TODO: add font family and recover filename from font family
        else
        {
            var renderer = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
            Bitmap bitmapImg = await renderer.LoadImageAsync(source, Context);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmapImg, 70, 70, true))
            {
                Gravity = GravityFlags.Right
            };
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}

The result is as follow depending on bindable property settings:

The xaml for this rendering is the following:
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}" x:Key="array">
        <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
        <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
        <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
        <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
        <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
        <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
        <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
    </x:Array>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<VerticalStackLayout Padding="20, 32" Spacing="20">
    <Label Text="Basic Icon Picker:" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <yourNamespace:IconPicker MaximumWidthRequest="200"
        Source="{FontImage FontFamily='MaterialIconsRound', Glyph={StaticResource IconMD_Expand_more}, Color={StaticResource DarkGray}}" 
        TextColor="{StaticResource DarkGray}" TitleColor="{StaticResource DarkGray}"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Title="Select a monkey"
        StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="{StaticResource DarkGray}"
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource array}">
    </yourNamespace:IconPicker>
    
    <Label Text="Picker with rounded corners:" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <yourNamespace:IconPicker MaximumWidthRequest="200"
        Source="{FontImage FontFamily='MaterialIconsRound', Glyph={StaticResource IconMD_Expand_more}, Color={StaticResource DarkGray}}" 
        TextColor="{StaticResource DarkGray}" TitleColor="{StaticResource DarkGray}"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Title="Select a monkey"
        CornerRadius="50" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="{StaticResource DarkGray}"
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource array}">
    </yourNamespace:IconPicker>
</VerticalStackLayout>

The current state of my refactoring into MAUI handler is at this point:
public partial class IconPickerHandler : PickerHandler
{
    //public static readonly new PropertyMapper<IconPicker, IconPickerHandler> Mapper = new(PickerHandler.Mapper)
    //{
    //  [nameof(IconPicker.Source)] = MapSourceChanged,
    //  [nameof(IconPicker.StrokeThickness)] = MapStrokeThicknessChanged,
    //  [nameof(IconPicker.Stroke)] = MapStrokeChanged,
    //  [nameof(IconPicker.CornerRadius)] = MapCornerRadiusChanged,
    //};

    public IconPickerHandler() : base(Mapper) { }
}

// The android one
public partial class IconPickerHandler
{
    public static void MapSourceChanged(IconPickerHandler handler, IconPicker view) { Debug.WriteLine(nameof(MapSourceChanged)); }

    public static void MapStrokeThicknessChanged(IconPickerHandler handler, IconPicker view)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(nameof(MapStrokeThicknessChanged));
        if (handler.PlatformView.Background is LayerDrawable backgroundDrawable)
        {
            GradientDrawable? borderDrawable = (GradientDrawable?)backgroundDrawable.GetDrawable(0);
            if (borderDrawable != null)
            {
                borderDrawable.Thickness = Convert.ToInt32(view.StrokeThickness);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void MapStrokeChanged(IconPickerHandler handler, IconPicker view)
    {
        if (handler.PlatformView.Background is LayerDrawable backgroundDrawable)
        {
            GradientDrawable? borderDrawable = (GradientDrawable?)backgroundDrawable.GetDrawable(0);
            if (borderDrawable != null)
            {
                borderDrawable.SetStroke(borderDrawable.Thickness, view.Stroke?.ToPlatform() ?? Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(nameof(MapStrokeChanged));
    }

    public static void MapCornerRadiusChanged(IconPickerHandler handler, IconPicker view)
    {
        if (handler.PlatformView.Background is LayerDrawable backgroundDrawable)
        {
            GradientDrawable? borderDrawable = (GradientDrawable?)backgroundDrawable.GetDrawable(0);
            if (borderDrawable != null)
            {
                borderDrawable.SetCornerRadius(view.CornerRadius);
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(nameof(MapCornerRadiusChanged));
    }

    protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiPicker platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);

        IconPicker element = (IconPicker)VirtualView;

        GradientDrawable borderDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        borderDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        borderDrawable.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        borderDrawable.SetCornerRadius(element.CornerRadius);
        borderDrawable.SetColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(element.BackgroundColor?.ToPlatform() ?? Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
        borderDrawable.SetStroke(Convert.ToInt32(element.StrokeThickness), element.Stroke?.ToPlatform() ?? Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new([borderDrawable, GetImageSourceAsDrawable(element.Source).Result]);
        layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 20, 0, 0, 0);

        platformView.Background = layerDrawable;
    }

    private async Task<Drawable> GetImageSourceAsDrawable(ImageSource source)
    {
        Drawable drawable;
        if (source is FontImageSource fontSource)
            drawable = new FontDrawable(Context, fontSource.Glyph, fontSource.Color.ToPlatform(), Convert.ToInt32(fontSource.Size), "MaterialIconsRound-Regular.otf"); // TODO: add font family and recover filename from font family
        else
        {
            var renderer = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
            Bitmap bitmapImg = await renderer.LoadImageAsync(source, Context);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(Context.Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmapImg, 70, 70, true))
            {
                Gravity = GravityFlags.Right
            };
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}

EDIT: The fontDrawable source code for testing purpose, all it do is getting a font from a font file set in Resources/Fonts and Draw the glyph text:
internal class FontDrawable : Drawable
{
    private int alpha = 255;
    private int size;
    private string text;
    private readonly TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();

    public override int IntrinsicWidth => this.size;

    public override int IntrinsicHeight => this.size;

    public override bool IsStateful => true;

    public override int Opacity => this.alpha;

    public FontDrawable(Context context, string text, Android.Graphics.Color iconColor, int iconSizeDP, string font = "ionicons.ttf")
    {
        this.text = text;

        this.paint.SetTypeface(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, font));
        this.paint.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Fill);
        this.paint.TextAlign = Android.Graphics.Paint.Align.Center;
        this.paint.Color = iconColor;
        this.paint.AntiAlias = true;
        this.size = GetPX(context, iconSizeDP);
        this.SetBounds(0, 0, this.size, this.size);
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        this.paint.TextSize = this.Bounds.Height();
        var textBounds = new Android.Graphics.Rect();
        this.paint.GetTextBounds(this.text, 0, 1, textBounds);
        var textHeight = textBounds.Height();
        var textBottom = this.Bounds.Top + (this.paint.TextSize - textHeight) / 2f + textHeight - textBounds.Bottom;
        canvas.DrawText(this.text, this.Bounds.Right - this.Bounds.Right / 10, textBottom, this.paint);
    }

    public override bool SetState(int[] stateSet)
    {
        var oldValue = paint.Alpha;
        var newValue = stateSet.Any(s => s == global::Android.Resource.Attribute.StateEnabled) ? this.alpha : this.alpha / 2;
        paint.Alpha = newValue;
        return oldValue != newValue;
    }

    private static int GetPX(Context context, int sizeDP)
    {
        return (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, sizeDP, context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
    }

    private static bool IsEnabled(int[] stateSet)
    {
        return stateSet.Any(s => s == global::Android.Resource.Attribute.StateEnabled);
    }

    public override void SetAlpha(int alpha)
    {
        this.alpha = alpha;
        this.paint.Alpha = alpha;
    }

    public override void SetColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter)
    {
        this.paint.SetColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    public override void ClearColorFilter()
    {
        this.paint.SetColorFilter(null);
    }
}

I tried both to set platform View properties on Map methods for property changed event and in ConnectHandler but nothing seems to work.
In debug the ConnectHandler platform code is properly executed.
The picker result with the handler doesn't take in account any change and display the basic Android picker:

Thanks.

I can't create a sample because your code missed the namespace of the FontDrawable. In addtition, did the MapCornerRadiusChanged trigger when the CornerRadius property changed?

I added the FontDrawable source code, and added a bit more details. Every Map method is triggered on property set, or when changing at running time with hot reload.

When I tested it, the LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new([border, GetDrawable(element.Source).Result]); always threw null exception.

You can try to keep the SetPickerUi(IconPicker element) method and the GetImageSourceAsDrawable in the handler as you did in the custom render. And just call Control.Background = SetPickerUi(element); in every map method.

The null exception is probably coming from the fact that there is no font importer or the font doesn't contain any associated glyph passed.
i tried your suggestion to execute the OnElementChanged content of renderer into each static map method, the result is still the same no impact in the rendering of the component.
EDIT: I modified my post to provide some xaml example.

How can I reproduce the problem or could you please provide a samllest sample?

at this link: https://github.com/guillaume-dore/UiToolkit.Maui, there is a sample project which is already set and use the picker.

I cloned this repo and reproduce you problem. The answer Christine provided can resolve it. In addition, you can also call the method in the code behind and it will work. You can report this as a new issue on the github repo.

In your shared code, create a partial handler
public partial class IconPickerHandler : PickerHandler
{
}

In your Android platform, create a partial handler in the same namespace
public partial class IconPickerHandler : PickerHandler
{
    IconPicker Picker => VirtualView as IconPicker;
    protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiPicker platformView)
    {
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
        Picker.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    protected override void DisconnectHandler(MauiPicker platformView)
    {
        Picker.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlatformView.Background = SetPickerUi(Picker);
    }

    private LayerDrawable SetPickerUi(IconPicker element)
    {
        GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
        border.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        border.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        border.SetCornerRadius(element.CornerRadius);
        border.SetColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(element.BackgroundColor?.ToAndroid() ?? Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent));
        border.SetStroke(Convert.ToInt32(element.StrokeThickness), element.Stroke?.ToAndroid() ?? Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new([border, GetDrawable(element.Source).Result]);
        layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 20, 0, 0, 0);
        return layerDrawable;
    }

    private async Task<Drawable> GetDrawable(ImageSource source)
    {
        Drawable drawable;
        if (source is FontImageSource font)
            drawable = new FontDrawable(Context!, font.Glyph, font.Color.ToAndroid(), Convert.ToInt32(font.Size), "MaterialIconsRound-Regular.otf"); // TODO: add font family and recover filename from font family
        else
        {
            var renderer = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
            Bitmap bitmapImg = await renderer.LoadImageAsync(source, Context);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(Context.Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmapImg, 70, 70, true))
            {
                Gravity = GravityFlags.Right
            };
        }
        return drawable;
    }
}

Create a similar partial handler in the iOS platform.
Add the handler definition to your MauiProgram.cs
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
                    handlers.AddHandler<IconPicker, IconPickerHandler>(); 
                })

